# How to hide Android ActionBar during Facebook Login?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a regular workflow. It all starts with login page, with a "Login with Facebook" button. If user press this button this this button a Facebook Login page appear. In case of success the app home screen appear.

I want ActionBar to appear after successful login. So no ActionBar during startup, no ActionBar on login page, no ActionBar behind Facebook login form.

I can hide ActionBar on login page from Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="hu.go.abs_style_test.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="hu.go.abs_style_test.MainActivity" />
```

But I can't hide it behind Facebook login form:

[image: facebook login form with action bar]

I want to use ActionBar after login page, so this isn't possible, since ActionBar will be null after:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Oh, and one more thing: I'm using `ActionBarSherlock`.

Comment: Can't you hide the action bar programmatically using `getActionBar().hide();`?

Comment: I can hide action bar on login and home page, but not behind fb login form, I can't modify action bar via android.app.Activity.

Comment: Ohh, I'm talking about modifying this activity: com.facebook.LoginActivity

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you hide you ActionBar programmatically (and not in XML files) using `getSupportActionBar().hide();` while you are displaying the Facebook login popup, then call `getSupportActionBar().show();` when the focus goes back to you application.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

solved my issue.